# BadRequest (400) with Substatus 1001 when adding new item in Azure Cosmos DB using Microsoft.Azure.CosmosRepository library

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, azure-cosmosdb, .net-6.0

I getting an issue while creating a new item with `CreateAsync` method in Azure Cosmos DB using the `Microsoft.Azure.CosmosRepository`(https://www.nuget.org/packages/IEvangelist.Azure.CosmosRepository) library `7.0.1` version with .NET 6 Web Api application. I am receiving a `BadRequest (400) response with Substatus 1001`.

Here are the details:

I have a method `AddEmailTemplate` that updates an email template in the repository. However, when I execute the update operation, I receive the following error:

> Cosmos query executed for item type EmailTemplate with a charge of 2.8
> RUs Query: {"query":"SELECT VALUE root FROM root WHERE
> ((((root["NotificationType"] = 3) AND (root["NotificationSubType"]
> = "")) AND (root["Language"] = "en-US")) AND ((NOT IS_DEFINED(root["Type"])) OR (root["Type"] =
> "EmailTemplate")))"} fail:
> SFH.N3.WebApi.Controllers.EmailTemplates.EmailTemplateController[0]
> An error occurred while updating email template, RequestId:338bcaa9-f8a3-418b-932b-4d88a7ab6a08
> Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.CosmosException : Response status code does not indicate success: BadRequest (400); Substatus: 1001;
> ActivityId: 5242793b-f785-436d-9565-5d7c1e730ef4; Reason: ();
> at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.ResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
> at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.CosmosResponseFactoryCore.ProcessMessage[T](ResponseMessage
> responseMessage, Func`2 createResponse) at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.ContainerCore.CreateItemAsync[T](T item, ITrace trace, Nullable`1 partitionKey, ItemRequestOptions
> requestOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.ClientContextCore.RunWithDiagnosticsHelperAsync[TResult](String
> containerName, String databaseName, OperationType operationType,
> ITrace trace, Func`2 task, Func`2 openTelemetry, String operationName,
> RequestOptions requestOptions)
> at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.ClientContextCore.OperationHelperWithRootTraceAsync[TResult](String
> operationName, String containerName, String databaseName,
> OperationType operationType, RequestOptions requestOptions, Func`2 task, Func`2 openTelemetry, TraceComponent traceComponent, TraceLevel
> traceLevel)
> at Microsoft.Azure.CosmosRepository.DefaultRepository`1.CreateAsync(TItem
> value, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

```
private async Task AddEmailTemplate(AddEmailTemplateCommand command)
        {
            var emailTemplateExist = await _repository
                .GetAsync(x => x.NotificationType == command.NotificationType
                && x.NotificationSubType == command.NotificationSubType
                && x.Language == command.Language).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

            // Insert email template
            if (emailTemplateExist == null)
            {
                var emailTemplate = new EmailTemplate
                {
                    Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                    NotificationType = command.NotificationType,
                    NotificationSubType = command.NotificationSubType,
                    EmailSubject = command.EmailSubject,
                    Language = command.Language,
                    TemplateId = command.TemplateId,
                };
                await _repository.CreateAsync(emailTemplate);
            }
            else
            {
                string message = $"Email template already exists for the specified notification type:{command.NotificationType}";
                _logger.LogWarning(message);
                throw new EmailTemplateAlreadyExistsException(message);
            }
        }
```

EmailTemplate class:

```
[Container(nameof(EmailTemplate))]
    [PartitionKeyPath("/NotificationType")]
    public class EmailTemplate : Item
    {
       
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "NotificationType")]
        public int NotificationType { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "NotificationSubType")]
        public string NotificationSubType { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Language")]
        public string Language { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "TemplateId")]
        public string TemplateId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "EmailSubject")]
        public string EmailSubject { get; set; }

        protected override string GetPartitionKeyValue() => NotificationType.ToString();
       
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "_ts")]
        public long Timestamp { get; set; }
       
        [JsonIgnore]
        public DateTime TimestampAsDateTime => DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds(Timestamp).DateTime;
    }
```

appsettings.json:

```
"RepositoryOptions": {
    "CosmosConnectionString": "AccountEndpoint={CosmosDbConnectionString}",
    "DatabaseId": "TestDb",
    "OptimizeBandwidth": true,
    "ContainerPerItemType": true,
    "AllowBulkExecution": true,
    "SerializationOptions": {
      "IgnoreNullValues": true,
      "PropertyNamingPolicy": "Default"
    }
  }
```

Cosmos Db Container:

[image]

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue. Is there any specific meaning for Substatus 1001 in this context? How can I further investigate and resolve this error?

But `GetAsync` method is working fine, when I am retrieving the existing items (`var emailTemplates = await _repository.GetAsync("{query}");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the documentation for that error code: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/troubleshoot-bad-request#wrong-partition-key-value

It means the Partition Key is incorrectly specified. There is a mismatch between the Container's Partition Key Definition and the property being send as Partition Key.

Double check on the Container's Partition Key Definition if it's indeed `/NotificationType` and if the `NotificationType` property has a correct supported value type.

Comment: Yes! I cross verified the container's partition key definition, it is correctly specified and also properly being send as Partition Key. I also updated my question and added my cosmos Db container with partition key value. This is very weird issue and not sure why it is not allowing me to add new item.

Comment: One more thing I noticed, As `NotificationType` is my partition key field, and it is `integer` data type, but when I changed this field data type from `int` to `string` it starts working and I am able to insert new item with `CreateAsync` method. So is it mean we cannot use `integer` data type for partition with this library?

Comment: That would be a question for the library authors. From Cosmos DB side, numbers are valid Partition Key values but the library might be extracting the value from the property in a way that assumes it is always a string.

Comment: Thanks! I have raised a question for the library author. https://github.com/IEvangelist/azure-cosmos-dotnet-repository/issues/331